# Reset keymapping of Capslock and Escape by Gnome Tweak Tool

Tags: fedora, gnome, settings

Ok, I've tried everything and gnome tweak tool isn't working so I'm done trying to get that fixed. I'm running Fedora 27 and I want to reset the keymapping of the caps lock to escape. I know I set it in gsettings but I'm not finding the correct schema and keys.

Does anyone know the those two are so I can set the mapping back so caps lock and escape work normally?